# Google Analytics API in inserting goals using PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, goal-tracking

I need help regarding the returned error after initiating request:

**Here's the request body:**

```
{
  "name": "Test Leads",
  "id": "2",
  "type": "Event",
  "active": true,
  "eventDetails": {
    "eventConditions": [
      {
        "type": "Category",
        "comparisonType": "EQUAL",
        "expression": "Leads"
      },
      {
        "type": "ACTION",
        "comparisonType": "EQUAL",
        "expression": "Create"
      }
    ],
    "useEventValue": true
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
{"error":{
    "errors":[
      {"domain":"global","reason":"backendError","message":"Backend Error"}
    ],
    "code":500,
    "message":"Backend Error"
  }
}
```

**Expected Goal Details when successfully posted:**
https://www.screencast.com/t/5QOJ28Tnk

Can someone check the code and see what's wrong or missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

````
  "name": "Test Leads",
  "kind": "analytics#goal",
  "id": "2",
  "type": "Event",
  "active": true,
  "eventDetails": {
    "eventConditions": [
      {
        "type": "CATEGORY",
        "matchType": "EXACT",
        "expression": "Leads"
      },
      {
        "type": "ACTION",
        "matchType": "EXACT",
        "expression": "Create"
      }
    ],
    "useEventValue": true
  }
}```
````